# Javascript error in IE11 for Google reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, recaptcha

I have implemented recaptcha on my site but it doesnt work in IE11.
I get this console error:
SCRIPT5005: String expected
recaptcha__en.js (17,24)

Any ideas what this may be and why IE is complaining?

Comment: Only an error message will not help to find the cause for the issue. Please inform us, which kind of project you are developing and which exact version of it you are using? Post some sample code that can give an idea about the issue. In my search results, I found that some users met with similar issues before but without knowing about your project. It will not help to provide suggestions based on assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the script src for google ReCaptcha from index.html and used loadRecaptchaScript=true in vue-recaptcha.

Comment: At what point did the OP mention using Vue.js on their site?

Comment: I got this error on my Vue.js environment, so I assumed that this error is got from Vue.js